# mongorestore collections with metoer running on local windows 10

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a dump folder which was created few year ago using mongodump, and want to use this info with a newly created metor app which is the same as the old meteor app after few packages updates and runs without errors.

I installed the mongodb server on this windows 10, the cmd mongo prints

> connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
>   MongoDB server version: 4.2.7

what is the "best" way to use the info with the meteor app.

Can some one  please give the overview of how all this things work together and then how to use the old info "including the command mongorestore" with the newly created metoer app?

It has been few years so will need polish my thinking on meteor and mongodb again.

My understanding is mongorestore the backup, then run the mongodb server in a separate cmd window, issue a cmd to connect to the restored database, and somehow tell meteor to use this server. Ok I give up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor comes with a bundled MongoDB in development mode, where the mongodb always runs on the app's port + 1 (app: 3000 = mongo: 3001).

You can simply start your Meteor app and when running open a new console and cd into your project folder, then enter:

```
mongorestore -h localhost:3001 --db meteor /path/to/dump/
```